# Is there any way to assign serial number to firebase childs?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way to assign serial number to firebase childs?
I tried to do with functions but for high speed data there is some data duplication.

Comment: I don't know your platform but using push() or childByAutoId() will always generate unique keys.

Comment: What I mean by serial number was, a running number which I can assign as an order number or something. writing a cloud function helped me to solve this.

Comment: Yes, What I suggested in my first comment is common practice as push() or .childByAutoID creates a guaranteed unique key which would be ideal to use as an order number because it's always unique and auto generating.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can

> write a firebase cloud function with onCreate trigger on each child.
>   then set a counter globally
>   add it using cloud on each trigger 
>   make your own cloud serial number

Comment: Please provide some code snippet or examples to be more useful